# Card image not displaying coming from a URL with Material UI and CardMedia component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am building a blog app that displays the latest post on the home screen using a Material UI card component. So far I haven't been able to get the image to show up. I have a JSON file containing all of my posts and image URL data. I am trying to get the URL from the file and put it into the card.

I have tried using a template string and directly passing  in the URL. I have also tried the  tag but that does not work either.

This is what I think should work:

```
<CardMedia
    component="img"
    sx={{ maxWidth: '75%' }}
    image={lastPost.url}
    alt="hero image"
    height="500"
/>
```

Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with the "image={lastPost.url}". Within the JSON file the image URL was wrong. Instead of, for example, https://unsplash.com/photos/A5rCN8626Ck, the correct URL would be: https://source.unsplash.com/A5rCN8626Ck.